# Loop a collection made by VBA class

Tags: vba, loops, class, object

I'm trying to loop a collection. I can expand and see "the elements" inside VBE but get the error:

> "Object doesn't support this property or method".

In a standard module I have

```
Public collItems As Collection
```

The collection is populated inside a userform module on initialization

```
collItems.add cItems
```

`cItems` is an object made from `New clsItems`, which is the class module.

The class module consists of many userform controls like this:

```
Private WithEvents frm As msforms.Frame
Private WithEvents lbl As msforms.Label
Private WithEvents cmd As msforms.CommandButton
Private WithEvents txt1 As msforms.TextBox
Private WithEvents txt2 As msforms.TextBox 
+++
```

Not sure if `Private` is the way to go on this.

When the userform finishes loading, a dynamic number of frames with all these textboxes inside each frame appears. It looks like a spreadsheet made from data inside MS Project. The command buttons job is to change a lot of the textbox's attributes/properties.

I want to loop the collItems collection but then I get an error.

I don't have any `get`  or `let`  in my class, just a single `set` property.
It might look stupid to add 10 unique textboxes inside the class, but that's how I made it work so far. All the form objects are given names that refer to row and column during creation and helps me identify them.

The failing code looks like this:

```vb
Sub changeBox(ByRef name As String)
For Each item in collItems.item(CLng(Replace(name, "cmd", "")))
    'blabla
Next item
End Sub
```

This test works and shows all the elements I want to loop:

```
Set test = collItems.item(3) 'Meaning row 3 in userform
```

How do I loop my specific textboxes and change their attributes?

Comment: I think you need to reference the collection by the key and get the item.  So `col("commandbutton1").item`  If you are adding with the control name as the key, but you would need to add the key name when adding to the collection.

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I assume you mean like `collItems.Add cItems, CStr(some string)`? I set plenty of properties before I add cItem to the collection. Meaning I only get to set one key for each row, hence unable to reference the columns of each row later?
Is there a way to specify which "sub-element" inside the collection I'd like the value from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> So now I want to loop the collItems collection and write my code. But then I get an error...

The collection holds a sequence of objects of type `cItems`. Thus to loop the collection items, declare an object of this type to be used as the iterator.

Note, the class members must be publicly exposed in order to be accessible outside the `cItems` class. Not sure how you instantiate them, but they could be exposed through a public read-only property.

```
Public Property Get Form() As msforms.Frame
    Set Form = frm
End property
```

To loop:

```
Dim objCurrent As cItems, frm As msforms.Frame  

For Each objCurrent in collItems
     'here you can use the objCurrent to access the current item.
    Set frm = objCurrent.Form
    '...
Next objCurrent
```

---

To be able to get a control by name, create a dictionary in the `cItems` class to store the controls and use the key to retrieve the objects.

See an example below:

```
'dictionary
Private m_boxes As Object

Public Sub AddTextBox(ByVal Key As String, ByVal obj As msforms.TextBox)
    m_boxes.Add Key, obj
End Sub

Public Function GetTextBox(ByVal Key As String) As msforms.TextBox
    Set GetTextBox = m_boxes(Key)
End Function

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_boxes = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
End Sub

Private Sub Class_Terminate()
    Set m_boxes = Nothing
End Sub
```

The to call it:

```
Dim txt As msforms.TextBox
Set txt = objCurrent.GetTextBox("txt1")
```

Comment: That kind of works, letting me loop through the "main collection", but each item inside the collection has "sub-items". Is there a way to loop them? I have `txt1` all the way to `txt10`, and I know which one I want to access. Is there any way to `set` the right "txt-object" through a string variable?

Comment: I btw assume that `dim objCurrent As cItems` should have been the name of the class, `clsItems`? I didn't get assigning objCurrent as the collection name variable to work

Comment: A workaround could be to create a new collection with just the values of the objCurrent, and then all the sub items would become iterable. Doable, but it's probably very bad coding...

Comment: `objCurrent ` is just the object that loops and gives access to the current item in main collection. To loop the inner collection (txt1, txt2, txt3 etc), get a reference to the inner collection as shown above and then loop it. You can also create a function in `clsItems` that takes a string argument and returns the relevant object.

Comment: See edit above, hope it helps.

Comment: Smart. What would be the smoothest way to add the necessary keys to the dictionary? I guess `txt1`, `txt2` and so forth needs to be added using  `sub AddTextBox`?

Comment: Correct. If you loop through controls, just use the control name - it's guaranteed to be unique. Also, when you add/read from a dictionary, it's always good practice to check if the key exists - see the doc here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/dictionary-object

Comment: Also, while the dictionary will happily store any control type, you will need separate insert/retrieve methods for each control type.

Comment: Thank you for your time so far! Classes are still a bit abstract to me. Still not sure when, where or how to run the AddTextBox. My google results for Dictionary vs Collection was a bit mixed, but I leanded on the one that said collections are faster. So I just made a new collection and added each txtbox with no looping. That worked well enough for me to continue my project. Thanks for helping me! I'll probably need this later for another project!

Comment: Don't worry, we've all been there. It will start making sense over time. FYI, collections are faster when accessing an item by index, dictionaries by key. Plus dictionaries give the option to look if an item exists without looping. Happy coding!